# Can I make centered desktop notifications?

Tags: gnome, display, notification, notify-osd, mint

## Edit

Now I am currently using `osd_cat`, installed with `xosd`.
It does the job perfectly for me since it is customizeable to my needs.
You can even choose a font from the output of `xlsfonts`

## Original Post

I would like to overlay custom text as a notification.

It is important that the notification is **non obtrusive** (does not take away window focus).

I made an 8 second video to show what I am trying to do:

[8 second sample clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OzQOZySCYqc)

I am aware of zenity, xmessage, and notify-send, and I don't think any of these can do what I am trying to do.

I am willing to use png's as overlays if custom text is harder to do.

This was inspired by Linux Mint's Change Workspace OSD:

[image: Linux Mint's Change Workspace Screenshot]

Comment: @JacobVlijm can you take a look at this one please ? Python should have something like that , right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

After some research , I have found a `gnome-osd` package, which by the way uses python, and installed simply with `sudo apt-get install gnome-osd`.

The properties , such as text location can be configured with `gnome-osd-properties` tool.  Sending messages is the same syntax as `notify-send`. The notifications are non-obtrusive. I've tested that with command `sleep 10; gnome-osd-client "This is a test message"` and switched on working in firefox until the text came up; I was still able to write in firefox even when notification was drawn on the screen.

Bellow you can see the example with test message:

[image]

Another alternative is to use `osdsh` , which works pretty much the same, launch the daemon with `osdsh` , configured with `osdshconfig` and send message with `osdctl -s  "TEST STRING"`

**Original Post**

`notify-send` doesn't specify options for location. Use `zenity` or `xmessage`

`zenity` gives centered popups by default. Example :

```
zenity --info --text "Hello world"
```

`xmessage` has to be configured according to `-geometry` flag specified in man page for X (`man x`). But you need to know size of your screen, which can be found with `xrandr` , `xprop -root` , or `xwininfo -root`. Example:

```
xmessage "Hello world" -geometry 250x250-130+100
```

Comment: Hey Serg! Hope your trip went well. As I mentioned in my question, it is important that the message does not take window focus. I don't think zenity, xmessage, or notify-send can do this since they all open up a new window, which removes focus of the previous window. I will edit my question a little to try to make this more obvious.

Comment: @TuxForLife Thank you ! The trip was alright. I don't know of any notification programs that can do what you're asking, but perhaps others others can answer that.

Comment: Ok, I found that many of the `gnome` user interface popups and dialogs are in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui` which i am assuming  is all javascript , which i don't know yet. However you might find someone who does, and write a custom notification tool like you'd like

Comment: I actually don't have the /usr/share/gnome-shell/js directory you mentioned.
I'm crossing my fingers your friend may help, it would be cool if there was something in python, since I am just learning it!

Comment: I researched a python module called "pynotify", I will try to see if I can do something with it.

Comment: I tried simple code with `pynotify`, it still shows notification at the bottom

Comment: found something, will edit my answer soon 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30418/discussion-between-tuxforlife-and-serg).