# How to display a ghost image over all other windows?

Tags: gnome, desktop-background

I want to show a near-transparent image over everything. I want to be able to use Ubuntu normally, despite the image.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Possibly the `osdsh` application.  Not sure how to use it.  `sudo apt install osdsh`

Comment: Possible:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/687132/can-i-make-centered-desktop-notifications